# 30" monitor that supports mini DisplayPort?

Tags: mac, display, displayport, mini-displayport

I want to buy a 30" monitor to go with my new MacBook pro, but the 30" monitor in the Apple store seems to use a dual link DVI connection (which requires a $100 adapter).

Are there any 30" monitors that use mini DisplayPort?

Comment: If you find any that do you may find that you can't get over 1920x1200 resolution from the internal video card.  A friend bought a specific Dell laptop that Dell support told him would be able to handle a 30" external via display port but it wouldn't.  He ended up getting an external video card.

Answer (score 2):

No, currently Apple's 24 inch monitor is the only mini-displayport monitor. I haven't even found any monitors that have mini-display port connection, let alone be in the 30 inch size/resolution.

Everything I have seen so far alternatively uses the full size display port. Dell's 3008/3007 and hp's 30 inch monitors are great alternatives if you are looking to save a few dollars.

- http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/category.aspx?c=us&category_id=4009&cs=19&l=en&nf=177~0~174493,4723~0~382981&s=dhs&~ck=anav&navla=4723~0~382981
- http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/382087-382087-64283-72270-3884471-3297215.html?jumpid=oc_R1002_USENC-001_HP%20LP3065%2030-inch%20Widescreen%20LCD%20Monitor&lang=en&cc=us

EDIT: Oo, I just found a mini-display port monitor. Not available in a 30inch though.

- http://www.cinemaview.com/product/cinemaview-24-display
- http://www.slashgear.com/first-non-apple-monitors-to-feature-mini-display-port-announced-1440979/

Comment: "Everything I have seen so far alternatively uses the full size display port." -- is there a mini-Displayport -> full-Displayport adapter? (This sucks!)

Comment: Yes, Circuit Assembly sells a mini displayport to displayport cable.  I'm using it to go from my Macbook to an HP display with a displayport connection.

http://estore.circuitassembly.com/products/Mini-Displayport-to-Displayport-Adapter-Cable.html

Answer (score 1):

> (which requires a $100 adapter)

**MonoPrice.com** is selling sanely priced [**Mini DisplayPort to HDMI Adapters**](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5311&seq=1&format=2) and [**Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapters**](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10428&cs_id=1042802&p_id=5106&seq=1&format=2) for **$9.75**

Comment: Neither of these support resolutions higher than 1920x1200 (why have a 30" monitor)

Comment: actually, some of those under-10-dollar adapters do: http://superuser.com/questions/616369/can-a-mini-displayport-to-hdmi-cable-support-resolutions-above-1920x1200/616431#616431

Answer (score 1):

The Dell 3008WFP supports displayport.
http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Displays/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=223-4890

Then all you'd need to pick up is a miniDisplayPort to DisplayPort adapter (These are pretty cheap).

Answer (score 0):

Just get a 30 inch with full DP plug, and buy one of those el-cheapo chinese miniDP-DP plugs on the internet.
http://www.marktnet.nl/Mini-displayport-naar-displayport-adapter-4687692.htm