# 2560x1600 @60HZ [miniDP --> DVI-D] adapter

Tags: display, resolution, dvi, mini-displayport, refresh-rate

Is it theoretically possible to achieve 60HZ signal at a resolition of 2560x1600 from a mini DisplayPort > DVI-D adapter?

I ask this because I have tried THREE adapters one $8, one $15 and one $32 and all three promised to go into resolutions of up to 4K @30HZ, and the latter promised explicitly to support 2560x1600 @60HZ, but when I connect these adapters on my eizo sx3031w or cg 303w (both 2560x1600 native) both adapters give the same signal error on both displays on their input 1 (which is a dual link input) and on the second input (which is a single link) I get a 1920x1200 signal. Why doesn't it work?

The monitors support the native resolution 2560x1600 ONLY on their dual link input1.

An 11-year-old DVI Nvidia card drives both monitors at 2560x1600 without a fuss, and the mini PC with mini DisplayPort drives my other Acer 4K @60hz, so both the monitors and computer work normally.

How can I convert mini DisplayPort >> DVI-D 2560x1600 @60HZ ?

A different but related [topic on 1920x1200](https://superuser.com/questions/616369/can-a-mini-displayport-to-hdmi-cable-support-resolutions-above-1920x1200) but it's clear that that is a very easy thing to achieve nowadays! The difficult step is 2560x1600 @60Hz conversion, apparently.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bandwidth limitation. Not from the adapter but the graphics card. Does it work if you set lower settings on the 2560x1600 display?

Comment: Thanks @LPChip for thinking with me mate. Well the pc is a quadcore i7 Gigabyte Brix 4770R PRO computer, well capable of driving the Acer 4K @ 60Hz (tested! perfect) via the minidisplayport > displayport cable. However when connecting it via a miniDP > DVI-D adapter I get this error on the monitor and since I cannot set anything (no screen on input1 !) So I have no way of testing lower settings AND I cannot image myself working with 30HZ so i really need a 2560x1600 @ 60HZ but the question is, is that possible with a miniDP > DVI-D at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support that high resolution even without converting it from mini Display Port you need a Dual Link DVI adapter cable. Essentially the resolution is so high the graphics card and the display, also the cable in between must support Dual Link DVI. Chances are that the display already comes with a compatible cable and most 5 year old graphics cards have it too.

[image: DVI-D DVI-I DVI-A]

To answer your question:
To get from mini display port to dual link DVI-D you can go with an unpowered one.

To get from mini display port to dual link DVI-I you most likely need an powered adapter, one that also uses power from a USB port to power the conversion. Apple sells one but I've heard they tend to die after a year or two.

Main difference is that DVI-I can output analog while DVI-D is exclusively digital, has fewer pins.

To be sure get the cheapest powered option below.

**Try this one for powered dual link DVI**

*Cheapest option:* https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6904 (it is mini displayport to DVI-D make sure you have the right cable)

[https://www.amazon.com/DisplayPort-Dual-Link-Adapter-Support-CAC-1051/dp/B00SOXO592](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SOXO592)

[https://www.amazon.com/Accell-B087B-007B-UltraAV-DisplayPort-Dual-Link/dp/B00856WJH8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00856WJH8)

Try this one for unpowered dual link DVI (might not work)

[https://www.amazon.com/DisplayPort-FOINNEX-Thunderbolt-Converter-Multi-screen/dp/B01GYC24H4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GYC24H4)

[https://www.amazon.com/VisionTek-DisplayPort-DVI-D-Active-Adapter/dp/B00DYRQXNO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DYRQXNO)

Comment: “To get from mini display port to dual link DVI-D you can go with a passive one.” – That’s wrong. Dual-mode DisplayPort only supports Single Link DVI/HDMI. Passive/active don’t refer to bus-powered/externally powered. Instead, it’s about whether conversion is involved.

Comment: Edited the answer I meant to say powered or unpowered. That's what I had in mind. As a user I don't care about how the conversion happens, it's the extra port that you need to use that gets you.

Comment: Thanks for accurate post! +1 *"you most likely need an powered adapter, one that also uses power from a USB port to power the conversion"* Indeed!  change "you most likely" to **"you must"** ;-) I got a StarTech USB-Powered(!) adapter and it works marvellously 2560x1600 @ 60HZ right from the get go, but it comes at a price of approx 100$. Such adapters are only worth it if you are planning on working more years on your old high quality old monitors without DP port.

Comment: Found a cheap powered version, edited answer in bold. https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=6904