# DisplayPort 1.2 to DVI-D adapter

Tags: display, resolution, dvi, displayport, adapter

I've been looking for a DisplayPort to Dual link DVI-D adapter that supports at least 2560x1600 (WQXGA).
The ports on my HP EliteBook 850 G5 docking station is marked with the DisplayPort dual-mode logo (DP++) and my monitor DELL U2713HM handles dual-link DVI-D.

Anyway, there are some older adapters DisplayPort 1.1 -> DVI-D + powered via USB with a higher price tag (>$100).
And there seems to be newer ones DisplayPort 1.2 -> DVI-D without any external USB power supply, and much cheaper price (<$100).

Active adapters with chipset Parade PS171 seems to be more backward-compatible with computer's port, and no longer require external power supply.

Passive adapters with chipset Parade PS8402A seems to require DP++ 1.2 port on the computer.

Is it something new in DisplayPort 1.2 that make DVI-D adapters simpler?
Are adapters nowadays plain "cables" with different end sockets, or is a traditional adapter, then a regular cable still recommended?

Also, old posts here on superuser.com mentions the only way to get 2560x1600 is to go with the more expensive adapters with USB power supply. Perhaps this is relevant for old computers (>5 years)?

> [Does a HDMI-to-DVI (dual link) adapter exist? I don't care about the price](https://superuser.com/questions/332099/does-a-hdmi-to-dvi-dual-link-adapter-exist-i-dont-care-about-the-price), [2560x1600 @60HZ [miniDP --> DVI-D] adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/1216506/2560x1600-60hz-minidp-dvi-d-adapter)

Answer (score 0):

This was solved after trying a 2-port DisplayPort switch and now everything works great in 2560x1440 resolution. Switching between the sources does not confuse the computers. My HP laptop adjust the main screen if the source goes away, and brings it back when turning it on again. I tested with the "Delock 87668 DisplayPort 1.4 Switch 2 port manual", without any external power supply.